# How to make R Script faster?

Tags: r, database, algorithm, optimization

I hope someone can help.

So, I have a data set that is around 400K rows, I'm having to use multiple loops and the code is painfully slow when running with R, I've read about vectorisation but I don't see how it can be implemented. I'm going to give a sort of analogous example so you have some context.

Suppose I have a set of data as follows:

```
Name | TimeStamp (UNIX time)
A      15
B      16
C      16
A      20
D      21
```

Basically, the names can repeat and the time goes forward (although it's possible to have multiple entries for a particular time).

This is how my code is written right now (I'm relatively inexperienced with R and coding as a whole so please excuse anything that doesn't seem standard).

```
dataIn <- read.csv('above table in csv format..') 
timeStamp <- as.numeric(dataIn$TimeStamp)
names <- as.vector(dataIn$Name)

#Unique list of names
uNames <- unique(names)
n <- length(uNames)

#Matrix data structure
countMatrix <- matrix(0, ncol = n, nrow = n)

threshold <- 5

#This is where it starts to take very long to run..(see: days)
for (i in 1:length(uNames)) {
  print (counter)
  counter <- counter + 1
  currentName <- uNames[i]
  for (j in 1:length(timeStamp)){
    currentTime = timeStamp[j]
    if (names[j]==currentName){
      futureIndex <- j
      futureTime <- currentTime
      tempLog <- numeric()
      while (((futureTime-currentTime) <= threshold) & (futureIndex <= length(timeStamp)) )  {
        futureName <- codes[futureIndex]
        futureNameIndex <- which(uNames %in% futureName)
        if (futureName %in% tempLog == FALSE){
          tempLog <- c(futureName, tempLog)
          countMatrix[i, futureNameIndex] = countMatrix[i, futureNameIndex] + 1
          futureIndex <- futureIndex + 1
          futureTime <- timeStamp[futureIndex]
        }
        else{
          futureIndex <- futureIndex + 1
          futureTime <- timeStamp[futureIndex]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

#This bit is almost instantaneous
for (row in 1:length(uCodes)) {
  standardNameNumberr <- countMatrix[row, row]
  countMatrix[row,] <- countMatrix[row,]/standardNameNumber
}
print ('normalisation complete..')
colnames(countMatrix) <- uCodes
df = as.data.frame(countMatrix)
```

So just for a brief explanation of what the code does (it is not entirely clear from the code...):

I want to answer the question, given that some name is called, what is the probability that another name (say B) will be called within a certain threshold? The idea is that I answer this question for A and all the other names then repeat the process for the other names.

Does anyone know how I can make this code quicker? As it is now it will days days to run through around 800k rows and my complete data set is much larger, I know that going going through the large data set multiple times can be time consuming but there must be some way to speed up the process? Any help will be appreciated.

---

So the output for the table given at the start would be the 'countMatrix' (using a threshold of 1 second):

```
    A    B    C    D    
A   1    0.5  0.5  0.5

B   0    1    1    0

C   0    0    1    1

D   0    0    0    1
```

The way this table would be read is rows are the events and columns are the following events. So reading from the first row, given that that A has been called out, the probability of B being called out within 1 second is 0.5, same for C and D. The probability of a name being called out within 1 second of itself is obviously 1. Note that repeats do not count, for example if B was called out at 15 seconds and 16 seconds we only care that it has gone off at least once within the time threshold.

I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Dear MathisHard, thank you for your question. Objects like data.frames or data.tables can definitely help in this case. However, in order for me to help you, can you provide something like an expected outcome and a reproducable example?

Comment: @zwep Thanks for replying, how do you mean? Should I not convert the read in CSV to it's vector constituents and just work on the data frame?

Comment: I would say keep using the data.frame, however I cannot be sure because I am unsure what exactly you expect the output to be.

Comment: Try profiling your code and see where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: I would bet you should use parallelization (see foreach or snowfall packages) *and* the `*apply` family

Comment: This code can probably be optimized, but we need you to give us an example of the desired output for the given example, and a clearer description

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I have added some more information, it should make it clearer

Comment: @BrunoZamengo I've tried my hand at some parallel processing as you recommended, I replaced my uppermost loop with foreach, reducing to 1/4 what it was at the start, I'm going to try and foreach the nested loop too, see if that helps, thanks!